# jq - Map Object values using startswith()

Tags: json, jq

I got two .json files, the first one contains the data:

> data.json

```
[
 {"ID_EXT_LARGE":"aaa_1234411","xy":"xyz"},
 {"ID_EXT_LARGE":"bbb_1474411","xy":"cfg"},
 {"ID_EXT_LARGE":"ccc_8944411","xy":"drt"},
 {"ID_EXT_LARGE":"aaa_1234411","xy":"kai"}
]
```

The other one contains the IDs:

> id_array.json

```
[
 {"ID_EXT":"aaa","ID_WEB":30,"ID_ACC":"one"},
 {"ID_EXT":"bbb","ID_WEB":40,"ID_ACC":"two"},
 {"ID_EXT":"ccc","ID_WEB":50,"ID_ACC":"three"}
]
```

Now I try to get the "ID_WEB" and "ID_ACC" propertie into the objects of data.json, using the mapping of ID_EXT_LARGE and ID_EXT.

The problem is, that ID_EXT only contains the first characters of ID_EXT_LARGE.
Expected result - (should be the extended data.json file):

> data.json

```
[
 {"ID_EXT_LARGE":"aaa_1234411","ID_WEB":30,"ID_ACC":"one","xy":"xyz"},
 {"ID_EXT_LARGE":"bbb_1474411","ID_WEB":40,"ID_ACC":"two","xy":"cfg"},
 {"ID_EXT_LARGE":"ccc_8944411","ID_WEB":50,"ID_ACC":"three","xy":"drt"},
 {"ID_EXT_LARGE":"aaa_1234411","ID_WEB":30,"ID_ACC":"one","xy":"kai"}
]
```

I tried it for ID_WEB and was thinking of something like this, (the for loop was just an idea):

> script.jq

```
  def getIDWEB(id_array);
        for i ....
          if ."ID_EXT_LARGE"|startswith(id_array[i].ID_EXT) then id_array[i].ID_WEB  end
        end  
    ;

  def setIDWEB(id_array):
     .ID_WEB = getIDWEB(id_array)
    ;

  ($id_array) as $id_array
  | map(setIDWEB($id_array))
```

Probably I am thinking too complicated and this is actually a one-liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach which builds a "table" object from `id_array.json`.  This function creates the table:

```
def maketable:
  reduce $id_array[] as $i (
    {}
  ; .[$i.ID_EXT] = ($i | {ID_WEB,ID_ACC})
  )
;
```

With the sample `id_array.json` in `$id_array` this returns an object like

```
{
  "aaa": {
    "ID_WEB": 30,
    "ID_ACC": "one"
  },
  "bbb": {
    "ID_WEB": 40,
    "ID_ACC": "two"
  },
  "ccc": {
    "ID_WEB": 50,
    "ID_ACC": "three"
  }
}
```

This function takes an object from `data.json` and returns the corresponding lookup key for the table:

```
def getkey: .ID_EXT_LARGE | split("_")[0] ;
```

e.g. given

```
{"ID_EXT_LARGE":"aaa_1234411","xy":"xyz"}
```

it returns

```
"aaa"
```

With these two functions the result output can be generated with:

```
  maketable as $idtable
| map( . + $idtable[ getkey ] )
```

Here is a script which puts everything together and uses `sponge` to update `data.json`:

```
#!/bin/bash
jq -M --argfile id_array id_array.json '

    def maketable:
      reduce $id_array[] as $i (
        {}
      ; .[$i.ID_EXT] = ($i | {ID_WEB,ID_ACC})
      )
    ;
    def getkey: .ID_EXT_LARGE | split("_")[0] ;

      maketable as $idtable
    | map( . + $idtable[ getkey ] )

' data.json | sponge data.json
```

Here is `data.json` after a sample run:

```
[
  {
    "ID_EXT_LARGE": "aaa_1234411",
    "xy": "xyz",
    "ID_WEB": 30,
    "ID_ACC": "one"
  },
  {
    "ID_EXT_LARGE": "bbb_1474411",
    "xy": "cfg",
    "ID_WEB": 40,
    "ID_ACC": "two"
  },
  {
    "ID_EXT_LARGE": "ccc_8944411",
    "xy": "drt",
    "ID_WEB": 50,
    "ID_ACC": "three"
  },
  {
    "ID_EXT_LARGE": "aaa_1234411",
    "xy": "kai",
    "ID_WEB": 30,
    "ID_ACC": "one"
  }
]
```

---

Note that as [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak) points out `maketable` could be replaced with

```
def maketable: INDEX($id_array[]; .ID_EXT) | map_values(del(.ID_EXT)) ;
```

if the more general [INDEX](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#SQL-StyleOperators) builtin (definition below) is available.

```
def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):  
  reduce stream as $row (
    {}
  ; .[$row|idx_expr| if type != "string" then tojson else . end] |= $row
  )
;
```

Comment: If your jq has `INDEX/1`, you can write the following instead of using `maketable`: INDEX(.ID_EXT) | map_values(del(.ID_EXT))